# echo is not entered into hash table

Tags: bash

When I calls the command echo, it is not entered into hash-table.

I tried several other commands, which are entered into the hash-table correspondingly.

```
$date
Sat May 25 01:16:40 CST 2019

$hash
hits    command
   1    /bin/date

$which date
/bin/date

$hash
hits    command
   1    /usr/bin/which
   1    /bin/date

$echo “123”
“123”

$hash
hits    command
   1    /usr/bin/which
   1    /bin/date
```

As you can see, echo is not entered into the hash-table. Similarly，command such as pwd is not entered into the hash-table either.

Comment: Stack Overflow is only for questions about *writing software*. Questions about usage or interactive behavior of standard UNIX tools should be on our sister site [unix.se].

Comment: BTW, relying on `echo` to have predictable or unsurprising behavior is generally a mistake. See the APPLICATION USAGE and RATIONALE sections of [the POSIX `echo` specification](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/echo.html), which explicitly recommend using `printf` instead to avoid places where intentionally-unspecified behavior differs between implementations. (Moreover, this avoids cases like bash's `echo`, which is *intentionally* incompatible with POSIX echo, which requires `echo -e` to print `-e`; whereas bash treats it as a flag to toggle XSI extensions).

Answer (score 2):

`which` is an external command, not part of the shell. Consequently, it has no way to know about shell builtins, functions, or aliases; so its output is frequently unhelpful. Compare to `type`:

```
$ hash -r
$ type date
date is /usr/bin/date
$ type echo
echo is a shell builtin
```

...and there's your difference. `echo` is part of the shell itself, so there's no need to search for an external binary, and thus no need to store that binary's location.

Comment: there is a file called echo in /bin.
Just curious, I wonder if this is the built-in function echo itself.

Comment: @Jack Chen No, /bin/echo is a separate program. 'echo' happens to be a builtin in bash with generally the same functionality as the binary /bin/echo. But in principle there may be shells that do not have a builtin 'echo', in which case /bin/echo steps in. If in a bash script you want the binary, just use the full path: `/bin/echo hello world`.

Comment: @JackChen, if it's built-in, that means it's *part of the shell executable*; thus, no separate executable is involved in its invocation. `/bin/echo` is for other cases where no shell is involved in startup. For example, when you say `xargs echo`, *that* uses `/bin/echo`, because it's using the `execve()` syscall to ask the OS to start an external program. Same thing if you run `subprocess.Popen(['echo', 'foo'], shell=False)` in Python; no shell, so it uses `/bin/echo`.

Comment: (please consider a "with `PATH=/bin`" to be implicit in my examples above of cases where `/bin/echo` will be used).